# Creating service-based COM instance from CLSID

Tags: windows, com, ole, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows Subsystem For Linux (new techonology in Win10) uses `LxssUserSession` service. This service is undocumented, but it is used as API for WSL (`bash.exe` uses this service to run ELFs). As i can see, it is part of COM: There is `CLSID` record in registry that has `AppID`. And `AppID` has `LocalService` record: `LxssUserSession`.

I am not familiar with COM, but if I understand it correctly, there should be COM component backed by this service. I am not able to create instance of this COM from script since there is no ProgID, but I tried to instantiate it using `OleView`. How ever, it reports that `CoCreateInstance` returned error. How to debug this error? Could it be that COM component can't be created and used for something different (i.e. there is some other interface). Is it generally possible to work with undocumented COM component? Can I trace `bash.exe` calls to this service (something like `logger.exe` or `ltrace` but for COM?)

Some background:
Here is error I am getting: http://s32.postimg.org/wpthro5kl/error.png

`bash.exe` != `/bin/bash`. `bash.exe` is PE (Win64 bin app) that connects to `LxssUserSession` and asks it to run `/bin/bash` (which is ELF (linux app!). `bash.exe` is better be called "WLS.exe", but for some reason they called it `bash.exe`.
Please see here: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/04/LXSS-diagram-1024x472.jpg and here is its headers http://s32.postimg.org/khjjf81th/bash.png . 
So, I am sure `bash.exe` uses COM to connect to `LxssUserSession` and `LxssUserSession` uses Pico (Psp..) functions to launch ELF as "pico process" (See here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/). 
Both are undocumented, but I believe I can use COM  some how, but I am getting error which I provided as first link:(

Comment: I've posted error and comment about bash, please see new version of my post

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting, and makes much more sense that the descriptions of WSL that I'd originally read.  So probably a genuine COM issue, nothing to do with WSL per se.  I've never used COM so probably can't be of much help, sorry - but a Google search on the error code brought up some results suggesting that you may need to call CoSetProxyBlanket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to instantiate object using `OleView` by setting default impersonation level to "Impersonate" in component services config (you may need to reboot). I can see `ILxssSession` interface now. But since there is not `IDispatch` and no TLB, there is nothing I can do: methods are unknown to me(

Answer (score 0):

I just doing the same kind of project. What I do is reverse engineering "bash.exe" to see how it work. Currently, I can create an insurance of `LxssUserSession` and call some method in it. But it still not complete. You can find it source [here](https://github.com/ExUltima/ELF-Runner).